# PHP - Form: save entries/selections on form submit

Tags: php, forms, form-submit

I have a PHP form that has some drop down selections and text field entries. If the user selects the wrong item from the dropdown, when they submit the form, I have it so that it will show an error message to the user and force the browser to go back to the previous page. The problem is that the user has to re-enter all of the information.

How do I make the form save the data until the form submit is successful?

EDIT:

Form submit method is `$_POST` and the form is being submitted to another page.

This would have to be done with strictly PHP as Javascript/Jquery solutions can be script blocked by more secure users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. This will work, and is not dependent on Javascript:

form.php //the form page

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<form method="post" action="action.php">
    <input type="text" id="input1" value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['fields']) ? $_SESSION['fields']['input1'] : '') ?>" />
    <input type="text" id="input2" value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['fields']) ? $_SESSION['fields']['input2'] : '') ?>" />   
</form>
```

action.php //the action page

```
<?php
    session_start();

    //do your validation here. If validation fails:

    $_SESSION['fields']['input1'] = $_POST['input1'];
    $_SESSION['fields']['input2'] = $_POST['input2'];

    //redirect back to form.php
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the form a POST or a GET? Either way, you have access to all the submitted fields in the PHP variables $_POST or $_GET. Within your HTML you can pass those values (if set), to the default value of each HTML input element. This way, if it is a first time, they will be blank, if there was an error, the values will repopulate.

Comment: This won't work if the form is submitting to a different page, right? If the form is in `form.php` and it is submitting to `action.php`, after `action.php` fails validation and redirects back to `form.php`, the `$_POST` would be cleared.

Comment: True. I assumed it was being submitted to the same page, which was probably a bad assumption.. In that case, when you redirect back to the form, you can stuff $_POST or $_GET into the session.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. Either add the data into `$_SESSION` or, when redirecting back to `form.php`, add the data to `$_GET`

Comment: @BenM: Submitting the form from `action.php` would require Javascript. If the browser doesn't have JS (not supported or turned off), wouldn't it fail rather spectacularly?

Comment: OK, or append the variables as inlinks? So they are thus available (i.e. `$_GET`)

Comment: I think we are "assuming" quite a bit. The developer hasn't even show us his code yet...lol

Comment: Method being used is `$_POST`. And the form is being submitted to another page. =(  I'm unfamiliar with the use of `$_SESSION`.

Comment: @Mechaflash: Posted answer on how to use `$_SESSION` to achieve what you need

Answer (score 1):

If they're select values, you can do something like this:

```
<select name="my_select" id="my_select">
    <option value="123"<?php if($_REQUEST['my_select'] == 123) echo ' selected="selected"; ?>>123</option>
</select>
```

If you have regular text inputs, you can simply apply the `$_REQUEST` variable to the `value` attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="my_text" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['my_text'] ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a preventing the page from navigating away from the submission until the data is verified. Enter jQuery :)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-library.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Wait for the user to click on your button
        $('#submit_button').click(function(){
            // Check each form field for an appropriate value
            if ($('#form_field1').val() != 'something I expect')
            {
                alert('Wrong submission!');
                return false;
            }
            // Forward the user to some url location
            window.location = 'url';
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish what I am suggesting...each of them have their own nuances and it may take some time to get this all working but at the end, I am betting it will make you happier...

Comment: Its nice to have Jquery do the form validation, but if Javascript is turned off and the validation falls on the PHP script, you'd want some way to repopulate the fields in that case as well

Comment: Nice comment but as I am saying above, all of these ideas are just ideas until we can determine if js is even part of the project or not. For now, we simply don't know.

Comment: @xbonez you're right about that. some people (like myself) use script blockers. So I would rather have it just perform the action on form submit rather than actively.

Comment: Using a script blocker on today's internet will break the entire web...for the most part

Comment: @Nur when you're working in the I.T. and Financial sector, it's a little more common to run into this problem. But I never said I wasn't going to use it =D. I would like a PHP resolution, but I know jquery and javascript are easier solutions.